# How to override product list / show name without copy the hole Prestashop theme?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a module to add a oneToMany link `Product->artists`.

This works perfectly on back office (CRUD + Product link on form).

Now I want to override the Prestashop 1.6 default theme to just add the artist name under the title for products list, product show and product popup.

I'd like to avoid the copy of the hole theme for just ten lines of HTML tags...

What is the best and proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prestashop theme system works as follow:

1. A module or a controller create a template file.
2. A module can override this template file.
3. The theme can override this template file.

If your theme is already handling this template file, you will not be able to change it in a module.

The simplest solution is to modify your theme template files.

---

If you want to add data to a template you can use [Prestashop Hook system](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks). In product page there are many Hooks:

- `HOOK_EXTRA_LEFT`
- `HOOK_EXTRA_RIGHT`
- `HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS`
- `HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS`
- `HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB`
- `HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT`
- `HOOK_PRODUCT_CONTENT`

If one of this hook isn't placed conveniently on the page, add a little JQuery to move it in the DOM as you want.

---

There's a workaround to this, but it's not a clean solution. You can override the product controller and instead of `$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'product.tpl');` declare your own template file in your module... That's really not a solution I would consider.

Comment: So the official answer is no. So bad. Why the second solution is not recommended? Because with that, I have to write only one file instead of copying the hole theme...

Comment: Ok I see why it's a bad idea, the `product-list.tpl` file is included on many template. So use another one will be overkill.